# Why Volatile doesn't work when the value of a field depends on its previous value

Tags: java, volatile

I came across this statement, for which I could not think of a reason.

> Volatile doesn't work when the value of a field depends on its
>   previous value

Any explanation with example is highly appreciated.

Comment: FYI...I found this statement in the book **Thinking in Java** by Bruce Eckel

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example:

```
volatile int i:

public void m() {
  if (i == 0) i = 1;
  else i = 2;
}
```

You could have two threads check the condition, see that i is 0 and set it to 1, although one would expect that two runs of this method would set i to 2. This is a classical "check-then-act" scenario.

The problem is that volatility gives you a visibility guarantee but no atomicity guarantee.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this through Check-then-Act scenario. I was confused on why/how volatility is dependent on a variable's previous value. does "Volatility behavior is not guaranteed when the value of a field depends on its previous value" is a more appropriate statement?

Answer (score 1):

"Doesn't work" is a pretty vague claim, but I suspect that the point is that if you have two threads each executing a loop with this code:

```
field = field + 1
```

... then even when it's volatile, each iteration is effectively:

1. Read
2. Perform computation with value we've read
3. Write

If one thread performs the read, then another thread performs a write, then by the time the first thread performs *its* write, it will effectively be ignoring the second thread's write.

So going back to our example, if you have two threads each executing a million iterations of `field = field + 1`, the total increase in the value of `field` may not be two million.

Comment: After your explanation, the statement in question does seem to be vague. Thanks for the details.